# C or C++ development in Roku

Tags: c, roku, brightscript

Is it possible to develop applications for Roku in *C* or *C++* as the SDK is written in *C*? If yes, how?  If no, then which languages other than *Brightscript* can apps be developed in?

Comment: @Olaf The slash is shorthand for or.

Comment: Fixed it for you. (Too many people who refer to "C/C++" seem not to be aware that they're different languages.)\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding is yes, at least with games and the Marmalade SDK https://www.roku.com/developer. I actually just downloaded the SDK and have not looked at it in much detail yet, but as it seems, developing for Roku involves a mix of Brightscript, C++ and Java (Android). Hope that helps!

Comment: From looking at the developer page for Roku, they seem to imply that the Marmalade SDK is intended for Games made for the Roku. Do you know if it is possible to use the Marmalade SDK for creating other types of Roku "channels"?

Comment: Marmalade itself is built for game development. So I'm assuming Roku "channels"  aren't built using the Marmalade SDK https://www.madewithmarmalade.com/products/marmalade-sdk

Comment: "Channel" just means an app in Roku's lingo and their appstore is named "Channel Store" or "Streaming Channels". "Games" is a category within said channels.