# How to compile C++ code for Roku?

Tags: c++, roku, brightscript

I have an android streaming client application which uses Java and cpp code. I want to port my application to Roku. I understand that Roku recommends only BrightScript for apps development.

1) According to this link ([C/C++ development in Roku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31540777/c-c-development-in-roku)), gaming application can be written in cpp using marmalade and compiled for Roku.

2) But this link ([How feasible is Roku app development with Marmalade?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32112090/how-feasible-is-roku-app-development-with-marmalade)) clearly says marmalade can not be used for streaming application.

3) My questions are
  (A) Is it possible to compile cpp for for roku?

(B) Where can I find the toolchain for building?

(C) If UI is developed using BrightScript, how can I call cpp functions from it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't. Not independently from Roku Inc anyway - you will need a very close collaboration from them, which means you should be able to persuade their business development/partners department you are worth time and money. In other words, your company better be a household name.

You cannot "find" the C toolchain, it may only be bestowed to you by the Co on individual basis, after approval and under NDA.

If you don't have special relationship (project/contract) with Roku Inc, for non-games you can only develop in BrightScript. It's a mandate, not recommendation.

Specifically for your case, best option seems to be to use the already existing streaming formats/components the Roku API already provides. BrightScript is a script language, not fast enough to write a codec.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use brightscript for Roku Streaming applications.

Comment: Thank you @abhishek. I think you meant cpp code can not be used for Roku. In that case if somebody wants to support a new codec in their media player, do they have to implement their codec in BrightScript?

Comment: In that case you have to contact to Roku Team, because publically they allow to develop the channels only in brightscript.